# Was it necessary for Luke to face Vader in order to become a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

In Return of the Jedi when Luke returns to Yoda, he makes the comment "So I am a Jedi." To this Yoda replies along the lines of, "You must first confront Vader. Only then a Jedi will you be."
Was it truly necessary for Luke to face Vader, in order to become a Jedi? Or was Luke already a Jedi, and Yoda was only making sure that Luke would still confront Vader?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Episode I, there's mention that for a padawan to become a Jedi Knight, they must undergo trials (Obi-wan states to the council that he's ready for the trials, as an attempt to cease being Qui-Gon's padawan, so Qui-Gon could then take Anakin as padawan).  Due to the collapse of the Jedi Order during Episode III, it seems Yoda's had to be creative.

Yoda provided Luke with some training in the Force and Jedi ways.  However, Luke never faced a serious challenge to this training.  Facing a Sith master would provide such a test, and prove Luke to be a true Jedi.  In the old ways, he would have graduated to become a Jedi Knight, but being the last living Jedi means he'll have to forge his own path forward.

In addition, so long as Vader and the Emperor were around, it would be difficult for Luke to do the other task that a Jedi undertakes - training future Jedi.  Any attempt to setup a new Jedi Academy would be crushed by the Empire, or we would have seen it occur during the time between Episode III and IV.

Comment: +1. Also, maybe Yoda was hoping that, in facing Vader and overcoming him without resorting to the Dark Side, Luke would become the real Jedi his father failed to be.

Comment: Are there trials required to become a Jedi Knight, too? I don't think Luke was talking about the transition from Knight to Master when he was talking about becoming a Jedi.

Comment: @Aether Ahh, you found the crucial flaw in my answer!  I'll edit it today to fix that.

Comment: Fixed it, the trials are to become a Jedi Knight.  Only experienced Knights became Masters.

Answer (score 11):

This is what is called a [Jedi trial](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Trials); it is a kind of final exam to achieve knighthood.

> In the latter days of the Order, both Obi-Wan Kenobi and Anakin Skywalker earned the rank of Jedi Knight without participating in formal trials, but rather passed their trials through their actions: Kenobi, through his duel with the Sith Lord Darth Maul, and Skywalker for his heroism during the Clone Wars.

It's not stated which trial (or trials) Luke is facing by confronting Vader, but it is the intent of Yoda. It could easily count as a challenge in all of the five fields (Skill, Courage, Flesh, Spirit, and Insight), but there are other actions by Luke that could also count as trials. For example, we could assume he failed his "Trial of Spirit" in the dark side cave of Dagobah, but succeeded the "Trial of Flesh" when he lost his hand to Vader in the duel in Cloud City.

Answer (score 4):

Yoda and Obi-Wan had already shown that they were not above lies of omission to manipulate Luke into doing what they wanted, so I think Yoda was just putting the screws to Luke one last time to get him to take care of Vader and the Emperor.  Given that Luke seemed to be the only person around with any Force training at all (besides the Sith), Yoda didn't have much choice, but that doesn't change the arbitrariness of what he was asking Luke to do to become a Jedi.  Luke had already faced Vader once and been carved up for his trouble, so sending him back without additional training seemed pointless even though it did (by some amazing stroke of luck) precipitate the demise of Palpatine.

Comment: I tend to agree, it would have made more sense to face a different but still serious trial before facing an opponent of Vader's caliber. On the other hand, I think it's part of the myriad of archetypes in the original trilogy, where the "hero-from-the-plains" ends up facing an impossible task and prevailing in a manner that suggests fate had to be involved in the whole affair.

Answer (score 1):

A Jedi must control his fear and anger.  Also, Luke had training, but nowhere near as intense a training as he would have received in the days before Vadar and Sidious.  The Jedi do not seem big on forced confrontations (notice how Obi-Wan always held back when Anakin jumped forward and that was an issue the Council had with Qui-Gon, as well -- he was headstrong), and seem to have no problem avoiding confrontations if they are not necessary.

There was no real reason why Luke had to face Vader and both Yoda and Obi-Wan considered Vader already lost to them.  (Destroying the new *Deathstar* would have likely killed both of them without a confrontation.)  Luke needed to go through a serious trial-by-fire to be sure he could control his anger, fear, hatred, and even love.

While there were many ways Luke could have been tested on that, there was no better way than for him to face his own Father and not give in to the dark side.

Comment: Note that, because of the totally-screwed-up timelines of Empire Strikes Back, Luke actually had a total of about 1 day's training.

Comment: It's called poetic license.  Either that or all the FTL issues resulted in time dilations!

Answer (score 0):

You can think it as a test. With enormous power, anyone can be deviated with dark side perk. As existence of Vader was due to the same thing, Yoda made it mandatory for Luke.

Answer (score 0):

Each master of the Jedi order has their own required trial for their Padawan to become a Jedi. This was Luke's test: not to give in to the dark side of the Force even if it results in his own death.